# Issue when logging unicode JSON strings in the console

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, unicode

I've made a web page (as a part of a Django app) where a JSON file is returned from a request made by the user. In the view for the page, I parse the JSON object and store the desired attributes in variables. I then add all of the variables to the context of the view so that they can be used in the corresponding html file. When I try to display each of these variables in the console, I get the error: 
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'`

I was thinking that the error could be resulting from the fact that the JSON attributes were being encoded as unicode so I tried to convert them by using the `str()` function as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-turn-unicode-strings-into-regular-strings) but for some reason, I'm still getting the same error.

What could be causing the error? If the error is because of the unicode encoding of the strings, how should I properly do the conversions?

Here is the view function:

```
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form_artistSelect = urllib2.quote(form.cleaned_data.get("artist_select"))
        form_city =   urllib2.quote(form.cleaned_data.get("city"))
        form_state = urllib2.quote(form.cleaned_data.get("state"))
        mile_radius = urllib2.quote(form.cleaned_data.get("radius"))
        #print "testing"
        url = "http://api.bandsintown.com/events/search?artists[]=" + form_artistSelect + "&location=" +form_city+","+ form_state+"&radius="+ mile_radius + "&format=json&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID"
        data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

        #titles = [ i.get("title") for i in data]
        raw_dts = [str(i.get("datetime")) for i in data]

        #formatted_dts = [i.get("formatted_datetime") for i in data]
        ticket_urls = [str(i.get("ticket_url")) for i in data]
        ticket_statuses = [str(i.get("ticket_status")) for i in data]
        venue_names = [str(i.get("venue").get("name")) for i in data]
        venue_cities = [str(i.get("venue").get("city")) for i in data]
        venue_region = [str(i.get("venue").get("region")) for i in data]
context = {
        "form_artistSelect" : form_artistSelect,
        "raw_dts" : raw_dts,
        "ticket_urls" : ticket_urls,
        "ticket_statuses" : ticket_statuses,
        "venue_names" : venue_names,
        "venue_cities" : venue_cities,
        "venue_region" : venue_region,
        "form" : form
    }
    return render(request,"searchform.html" , context)
```

#### EDIT:

The error is occurring inside of the html file that corresponds to the view in which I'm using the context variables for each of the JSON fields.

```
<script>
console.log( "form_artistSelect\n" + {{form_artistSelect}} );
console.log( "raw_dts\n" + {{raw_dts}} );
console.log( "ticket_statuses\n" + {{ticket_statuses}} );
console.log( "venue_names\n" + {{venue_names}} );
console.log( "venue_cities\n" + {{venue_cities}} );
console.log( "venue_region\n" + {{venue_region}} );
...
```

[Here](http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Miike%20Snow/events/search.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&location=Miami,FL&radius=150) is an example link for the JSON file that I'm requesting

Comment: Where are you getting the error? There is no obvious printing to console in this code and it seems somewhat unlikely you are getting syntax errors because of encoding.

Comment: Your `data` variable is the source of the problem. It comes with non-properly encoded `json` data. Please add it to your question.

Comment: That's a javascript `SyntaxError`, right? `str(some_unicode_value)` is risky... it fails if there are non-ascii characters in the string. Sticking with the original unicode values should work.

Comment: @memoselyk I just updated the post with more info about where the problem is occuring.

Comment: @pvg Check the updated post, thanks.

Comment: @tdelaney Should unicode also be used when storing the JSON data in a DB?

Comment: So you're getting the error in the JS console? That should tell you on which line. Can you look at the line in the generated HTML? Looks like a quoting thing

Comment: @pyg Actually I think that error was resulting from a previous commit to the repo. The issue seems to now be with the context variables not being referenced before they are defined.

Comment: Yeah, Unicode (Mostly) Everywhere. If its a string for people, and those people may speak something besides English, you should think unicode from the ground up.

Comment: @tdelaney Ok so it seems that one error had to do with the context dict not being indented inside of the if statement and also because there was no else statement. But now it seems that the strings are coming through to the template as numeric literals for some reason since I'm getting the error: ```SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal console.log( "form_artistSelect\n" + Miike%20Snow );``` Is this because of the ```str()``` conversions or is it something else?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is on the javascript side, and I don't know javascript. But the "Miike.." part isn't in quotes so maybe that's it. If `form_artistSelect` is generated in your template, I'd look at that part of the template itself. Just a guess.